# How to pass variable from postPersist Event listener to Controller

Tags: service, symfony4, event-listener

I have implemented an EventListener class and declare it in services.yaml
I'd like to return to my Controller a variable when entity is persited and send this variable to twig template. I want to show a step form in my view showing Entity name in green for example when data has been persisted in database. If it works I will use the same process in another controller where I persist multiple entities. To sum up: How to notify a controller that a specific entity has been persisted by passing a variable?

**The eventlistener**

```
<?php 

namespace App\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use App\Entity\Article;

class TodoListener {

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        if(!$entity instanceof Article) 
            return;

        $var = 'foo';
        return $var;
    }
}
```

**services.yaml**

```
App\EventListener\TodoListener:
    tags:
    - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

**Controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/new", name="blog_create")
 * @Route("/blog/{id}/edit", name="blog_edit")
 */
public function form(Article $article = null, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager)
{

    if (!$article) {
        $article = new Article();
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        if (!$article->getId()) {
            $article->setCreatedAt(new \dateTime());
        }

        $manager->persist($article); 
        $manager->flush(); 

        /**
         * Get back variable when entity is persisted ???
         */

        return $this->redirectToRoute('blog_show', ['id' => $article->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('blog/create.html.twig', [
        'formArticle' => $form->createView(),
        'editMode' => $article->getId() !== null
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: you can’t.

You can try to work around it with a custom symfony event, but is very bad.
If you want to know if an entity is new or already persisted you should call `getEntityState` on entity manager’s `UnitOfWork` or split the flows between actions (write two distinct actions for new and edit).

Anyway, just a suggestion: set the `createdAt` field into the entity constructor ;)